# Postgres: Match comma separated tags column value with pre-defined array

Tags: postgresql

I have an array: `{"test1",test2,test3}`

Table

```
id   tags
1    test4
2    test2
3    test3,test2
4    test1,test2
5    test1,test2,test3
6    test2,test1,test2
```

My condition to match if all the tags are present in the array. If yes, then pick all those records.

So here the result for the above scenarios should be

```
2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the contains operator for arrays:

```
select id
from the_table
where string_to_array(tags, ',') <@ array['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/IJT95673

Comment: you have to invert operator : <@ , not @>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if the array is: {" test1"," test2"}

Comment: Notice the space in the array element itself

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi: then add those spaces between the single quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM t
WHERE ANY(regexp_split_to_array(tags, ','))=ANY ( {"test1","test2","test3"})
```